# C: code matrix and repeating elements in descending order of appearence

Tags: c

Hello i want to print the given numbers in descending order of appearence .
example {1 2 5 4 3 1 6 3 1 3 5 1}
output
1 given 4 times
3 given 3 times 
5 given 2 times
2 given 1 times 
...............
...............
Array is sorted.
Anyway here is my code. if anyone has any idea please add.

```
int n,i,j,a,count,prev;
int pin1[SIZE];


for(i=0;i<=SIZE;i++)
      { do{
          printf("Give a positive number (1..9): ");
          scanf("%d",&n);
          pin1[i]=n;
          if(n<=0 || n>9)
          {
            printf("Give number within range (1..9) please!\n");
          }
        }while(n<=0 || n>9);
    }
printf("the numbers you typed are:[");

for(i=0;i<=SIZE;i++)
{
printf("%d ",pin1[i]);

}
printf("]");
 for(i=0;i<SIZE;++i)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<=SIZE;++j)
    {
      if(pin1[i]<pin1[j])
      {
      a=pin1[i];
      pin1[i]=pin1[j];
      pin1[j]=a;
      }
    }
}
printf("\nthe numbers you typed sorted descending are:[");

for(i=0;i<=SIZE;i++)
{
printf("%d ",pin1[i]);
}
printf("]");
prev=pin1[0];
count=1;
for (i=1;i<=SIZE;i++)
{
    if (pin1[i]==prev) 
    count++;
    else
    {
    printf("\nthe number %d is given %d times",prev,count);
    prev=pin1[i];
    count=1;
    }
}//for last number of array
   printf("\nthe number %d is given %d times",prev,count);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have loads of <= SIZE conditioning your `for` loop. Should be < SIZE...

```
int n, i, j, a, count, prev;
int pin1[SIZE];

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    do{
        printf("Give a positive number (1..9): ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        pin1[i] = n;
        if (n <= 0 || n>9)
        {
            printf("Give number within range (1..9) please!\n");
        }
    } while (n <= 0 || n>9);
}
printf("the numbers you typed are:[");

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", pin1[i]);

}
printf("]");
for (i = 0; i<SIZE-1; ++i)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < SIZE; ++j)
    {
        if (pin1[i]<pin1[j])
        {
            a = pin1[i];
            pin1[i] = pin1[j];
            pin1[j] = a;
        }
    }
}
printf("\nthe numbers you typed sorted descending are:[");

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", pin1[i]);
}
printf("]");
prev = pin1[0];
count = 1;
for (i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    if (pin1[i] == prev)
        count++;
    else
    {
        printf("\nthe number %d is given %d times", prev, count);
        prev = pin1[i];
        count = 1;
    }
}//for last number of array
printf("\nthe number %d is given %d times", prev, count);
```

You should really be using `qsort` it will do the work for you. There was also a counter error that would've been causing an unpredictable memory error in your nested loop. This has been changed also. But the logic appears sound.

Update=========================================================================

Given your clarification I think this should do what you want. I am surprised more folks haven't chipped in here. I have "refactored" the code slightly. Only got round to this today.

```
#define SIZE 6

typedef struct
{
    int num;
    int counter;
} Inputs;

void sort_(const void* data1, const void* data2)
{
    Inputs* input1 = (Inputs*)data1;
    Inputs* input2 = (Inputs*)data2;

    if (input1->counter > input2->counter) return -1;
    if (input1->counter < input2->counter) return 1;

    if (input1->num > input2->num) return -1;
    if (input1->num < input2->num) return 1;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n, i, j, a, count, prev;
    Inputs pin1[SIZE];

    /* initialise array elements */
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        pin1[i].counter = 0;
        pin1[i].num = -1;
    }

    count = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        if (j == SIZE) break;

        printf("Give a positive number (1..9): ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (n <= 0 || n > 9)
        {
            printf("Give number within range (1..9) please!\n");
            continue;
        }

        /* check if it already exists and increment the counter */
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (n == pin1[i].num)
            {
                pin1[i].counter++;
                pin1[i].num = n;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i == count)
        {
            pin1[count].counter++;
            pin1[count].num = n;
            count++;
        }

        j++;
    }

    qsort(pin1, count, sizeof(Inputs), sort_);

    printf("the numbers you typed are:[");
    for (i = 0;  i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("(%d of %d) ", pin1[i].counter, pin1[i].num);
    }
    printf("]\n");
    while (1){};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but i still looking of how to print the counts descending and not the numbers that the user gives.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code and then compile. It worked for me. It takes the input numbers and sorts the output so the numbers are printed in descending order. Is this not what you asked for?

Comment: Hi. yes it works but i try to print the appearence in descending order and not the numbers the user gives as input.

Comment: If I input "4, 5, 9, 1, 4" I get as an output "9, 5, 4, 4, 1". What do you want as an output form the given input (i.e. 4, 5, 9, 1, 4). I am having problems understanding exactly what you want.

Comment: ok output must be 2 times 4,1 time 5,1 time 9,1 time 1.i want the frequency to be sorted.I think it needs a second array.

Comment: See updated code. I rewrote it with a structure - just keeps things succinct. Your original code was fine and probably only needed a bit of extra work but this might prove easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you that is the exaxt code i was looking for and works ok has some issues with the function and the pointers returning void i will look into it!!!!!!!!!!